# SQL WHERE CONCAT LIKE NOT

Tags: php, sql

I try to make SQL to search some string in database.
In this spesification, The SQL must be dont display one string in database.

my sql like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `chatuser` WHERE CONCAT( `fullname`,`image`) LIKE '%".$search_string."%' NOT (`$string is not be displayed`) " ;
```

is that possible  ? 
Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you could want to do.  Your `where` clause doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` as two conditions would be:

```
SELECT * FROM chatuser
WHERE CONCAT(CustomerName,ContactName) LIKE '%t%'
AND CONCAT(CustomerName,ContactName) NOT LIKE '%m%';
```

You miss `AND` Between conditions. Also you have to repeat `CONCAT(CustomerName,ContactName)`.

In the example above we are looking for all CustomerName+ContactName with a **t** in any place but if it doesn't have an **m** in any place.

Comment: The expression compared with like needs to be repeated (`exp LIKE pat1 AND exp NOT LIKE pat2`) or another expression must be given, if the second comparison isn't meant to check the same expression.

Comment: thanks for help :) I already try , but get an error like this :

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

Comment: @dnysaz First run the query in the console (phpmyadmin in this case) hardcoding the data. If this is ok you have a problem with the vars in php.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs found at https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-like.php

> Example: MySQL NOT LIKE operator with (%) percent

The following MySQL statement excludes those rows from the table author, having the 1st character of aut_name ‘W’.

Code:

```
SELECT aut_name, country
FROM author 
WHERE aut_name NOT LIKE 'W%';
```

And so it seems would work in your situation.